# Embed an outside application into my own application window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode7

I am using Xcode 7 and Objc to build my own application UI.  I am trying to find a way to build an application UI that contains multiple other applications inside of my window.

Example:
I have a main window split up into 4 views. In the top right hand corner I want to embed the program [TextEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html) into this section of my UI. Below is a screen shot of my testing storyboard.
[Xcode storyboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BdXe.png)

What is the best way to embed an outside application written in Xcode into my own application window, without coping and pasting all of TextEdit's code into my own application?

Comment: TextEdit is written for Mac using Cocoa Framework for iOS devices you need CocoaTouch framework written files.

Comment: This application is written for OSX not IOS.

Comment: Well then I am not sure if there is a dependency manager for mac development. In the worst case you would have to add and copy the files to your project and call them in the  TextEdit view by making it a class of the required file

Comment: There is no way to do this on the mac. You have to write support for each app's functions in your app. I was recently involved in another project which tried to do this. On Windows (at least in 7) you can attach a process to a window.